# ruby shorthand for conditionals, when to use instance variables and efficiency of looping through parsed xml versus storing as hash

Tags: ruby

I'm learning ruby and have a few questions about some code I wrote for a newbie challenge.  Purpose of challenge is to find country with largest population from an xml document.

I've included my code below.  Questions I have are:

1. Is there a way to avoid having to initialize the `@max_pop` variable (`@max_pop=0`)?
2. Is there shorthand for combining the entire conditional block into 1 line?
3. Do I have to use instance vars `@max_pop`, `@max_pop_country`?  Got error without them.
4. Which is more efficient:

   1. Loop through each country and check if `pop > max_pop` (approach in code below)
   2. Create pop hash (`pop[:country]`) and then find country with highest pop
5. Is there hash method to return key value pair for largest element in hash (to do 4.1)?

Source Code:

```
@max_pop=0
doc.elements.each("cia/country") do |country|
 if country.attributes["population"].to_i > @max_pop
  @max_pop=country.attributes["population"].to_i
  @max_pop_country=country.attributes["name"]
 end
end 
puts "country with largest pop is #{@max_pop_country} with pop of #{@max_pop}
```

Comment: Show us an XML sample and we can probably streamline it a lot. Otherwise, get an array of arrays, containing the country name and population, and use [`max`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) or [`max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with rexml, but you ought to be able to simplify everything to something like this:

```
max_pop_elem = doc.elements.enum_for(:each, "cia/country").max_by { |c| c.attributes["population"].to_i }
max_pop_country = max_pop_elem.attributes["name"]
max_pop = max_pop_elem.attributes["population"].to_i
```

1. Yes, see above.
2. Yes, see above.
3. No.  You should use local variables instead of instance variables when possible.
4. Don't worry about efficiency of CPU time until you have a slow program.  Then use ruby-prof.  Until then, just worry about the efficiency of coding time (do things the easy way).
5. Yes, just do `key, value = hash.max_by{|k,v| v}`.

In general, if you are going to be iterating over things you should learn about Ruby's [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html) module.  I made a reference sheet for it [here](http://blog.davidegrayson.com/2012/03/ruby-enumerable-module.html).

Comment: If rexml supports enumerators properly, you can do `doc.elements.each("cia/country").max_by ...` but you should try the above code first.

Comment: Won't `hash.max` return the max key, not value? Ah, you fixed it.

Comment: oops yeah.  I thought I tested it beforehand by my test was wrong.  I fixed it now.